# Rhomobile inserting into local database using CSV or XML from external web server

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I am currently developing a Rhomobile application. I have a backend database which holds customer information. I have got from the webserver a csv string (or XML - I am able to parse the XML using REXML) which contains all the customers. Each time I sync the device I am going to reset the customer table on the device and re-insert all data from the backend database. I am not using RhoSync and the device will be using property bag.

Is it possible to use the CSV or XML data to insert into the customers table? If so, how would I go about it?

At the moment the only option I can see that would work would be to manually loop through the CSV/XML and insert into the database manually; this isn't very elegant.

Any help will be much appreciated, sorry if this is a dumb question; still relatively new to this framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that the only way is to loop through the csv/xml, which with the help of a database transaction this doesn't take long.

Using fixed schema also increases the performance a lot as property bag has to do column inserts (so if you have lots of columns - there is lots of inserts per record).

Also in Rhomobile garbage collection is turned off, so if you are trying to process large data sets your device will quickly run out of memory:

```
GC.enable
```

The above solves this issue